# List of un syncable files in Google Drive

Tags: windows-8.1, google-drive

My Google Drive client in Windows 8.1 tells me there are "135 unsyncable files". I clicked on the message and it lists me 3 files that "are not present on my computer". Actually, Google Drive automatically created duplicates of these files so it has problem with them.

While I can manually look at the supposed path of each problematic files and manually delete them, I can only see 3 of them at a time so it makes the process very time consuming.

I wonder if someone knows a way of the getting the full list of unsyncable files to streamline their erasing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted the Google Drive support over the issue. Among the solutions they suggested, the good ol' re installing worked:

Try unloading and reinstalling the application. To begin, let's get a fresh start by removing Google Drive and its folders. Please make sure you have anything of importance backed up before completing any of this process, since deleting files may have adverse affects on your data. You can use http://google.com/takeout to create an archive of Drive's contents.

Once everything is backed up, follow the steps outlined below:

```
1. Quit Google Drive.
2. Open the Run command by pressing the Windows key + R ;at the same time.
3. In the run box, copy and paste without the quotes: "%LocalAppData%\Google".
4. Press Enter.
5. Look for the Drive folder in this folder, and delete it.
6. Uninstall Google Drive by clicking the Start menu, selecting "Control Panel", then "Programs and Features". Find Google Drive and right-click to uninstall.
7. Rename Google Drive to something like GoogleDrive(Today's date). If you can't rename it, then move the contents to a folder outside of the Google Drive folder.
8. Empty the Recycle Bin.
9. Reinstall Drive from here: https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive.
```

Before re installing, I tried these steps, which could work for someone and is less complicated than the previous:

It sounds like the checklist Google Drive uses may be outdated. This is rare, but when it happens, you can update it by removing the outdated checklist.

To remove the Google Drive file checklist, you can go through the following steps:

```
1. Click on the Google Drive icon, in the taskbar on the lower right of your screen (next to the time). 
2. Now hold down the 'Shift' key on your keyboard while you click on settings (three dots).
3. Select the "Enable diagnostic mode" option close to the bottom of the list.
4. Within that popup window, click on 'Open the config directory'.
5. Look for the "cloud_graph" folder in this folder, and delete it.
6. Start Google Drive from the Applications folder. This will cause Google Drive to re-check the files that you've already uploaded and compare them to your local files.
```